# Sqlite-net guid select returns empty guid

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I'm developing a Windows Store App with sqlite as database. I'm using SQLite for Windows Runtime and sqlite-net. Trying to get a list of Guid from a table, but only getting empty guids in the list ({00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}). However when querying only for one guid it works as it should be.

My code is the following:

```
async void SyncSurveys()
    {
        SQLiteConnection _db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "SurveyDB"));

        var localSurveys = (from s in _db.Table<Survey>()
            select s.SurveyGuid).ToList();

        ...
    }
```

I've tried the query in the following format also, but it is neither works:

```
var localSurveys = _db.Table<Survey>().Select(s => s.SurveyGuid).ToList();
```

But if I'm using the following query, to get only one guid just for debug purpose it works well:

```
var localSurvey = db.Table<Survey>().FirstOrDefault().SurveyGuid;
```

In the not working scenario the list's count matches the table's rowcount. Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working with the list version?

Comment: Try using a `Parse` method, e.g. `_db.Table<Survey>().Select(s => Guid.Parse(s.SurveyGuid)).ToList();`. Not sure what's the data type of `SurveyGuid`, is it string in a database? This would usually happen when the code calls `new Guid()` instead of `Guid.NewGuid()` or `Guid.Parse*`

Comment: SurveyGuid's type is `System.Guid`, the table generated with the sqlite-net, but as I know in sqlite database isn't a thing called datatype, your datatype can by anything, like ChickenSoup or whatever. Your solution won't work, because `SurveyGuid` is a `Guid`, but `Guid.Parse()` expects string.

Comment: can you post the table structure to http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but it might put you down the right path.  I noticed there is an option that can be added to a connection string that sets if GUIDS are stored in binary or not

Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;BinaryGUID=False;

More info https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem should be the basic script commands are properly written. 
It may be a bug database.